# How can extract a tar file that is 1GB in size?

Tags: tar

How can extract a tar file that is 1GB in size? Does the server memory have to equal the file size or greater?

I have been running tar -xv $FILE and each time it never finishes.

Comment: Can't figure out how to delete this, so I will add this comment. I added the -f switch to it and it started extracting all the files.

Comment: It should finish eventually. And no, you don't need to have memory to hold the whole file. It should get by with just a single fixed-size buffer.

Comment: This question belongs to superuser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tar is just a user space program. Not that the server memory needs 1GB of space.

Atleast the server harddrive must have enough size(greater than 1GB) to hold the untarred files.